# How to convert Date from (ddmmyyyy HH:mm:ss) to (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS)?)

Tags: java, date, datetime

I am trying to convert date from (ddmmyyyy HH:mm:ss) to (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS) format.

Below is the code :

```
String startDate="06162019 00:00:00";
SimpleDateFormat inSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("ddmmyyyy HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat outSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
try{
   String outDate = "";
   Date date = inSDF.parse(startDate);
   System.out.println(date);
   outDate = outSDF.format(date);
   System.out.println(outDate);
}catch (final Exception e) {
   e.getMessage();
}
```

But i am getting wrong result :

```
Sun Jan 06 00:00:00 GMT 2019
2019-01-06 00:00:00.000
```

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Your first pattern uses `mm` in the middle of (presumbly) the year. `mm` is minutes, not months. Change first pattern to `ddMMyyyy HH:mm:ss`

Comment: Moreover, if the format is `ddMM`, and your example date starts with `0616`, that is the 6th day of the 16th month. There is no 16th month in the common calendar.

Comment: @RealSkeptic that's what i was wondering

Comment: Don't use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome. Your experience is not the only one, rather it is pretty common. The class is also long outdated. Instrad use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`. [Oracle tutorial here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you work with Java 8 or later. If so please drop old and horrible `java.util.Date` and and even worse `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` they are dead and buried. Switch to use of `java.time` package. in order to solve your problem you would need to do this:

```
String startDate="06162019 00:00:00";
DateTimeFormatter inSDF = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMddyyyy HH:mm:ss");
DateTimeFormatter outSDF = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
try{
   System.out.println(outSDF.format(inSDF.parse(startDate)));
}catch (Exception e) {
   e.getMessage();
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com.](https://ideone.com/YpUBS2)

> 2019-06-16 00:00:00.000

Read about [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). Also you might find this article interesting: [Java 8 java.time package: parsing any string to date](https://community.oracle.com/blogs/michaelgantman/2016/02/07/java-8-javatime-package-parsing-any-string-to-date)

Comment: I suppose that this will give you an exception stating that month of year cannot be 16? As should be expected as most helpful for the programmer.

Comment: I guess the incoming format then should be "MMddyyyy HH:mm:ss" Thank you Ole

Comment: @MichaelGantman  Can we add ("America/New_York") time zone in this?

Comment: Yes, you can. Look it up in the Javadoc for DateTimeFormatter class that I mentioned in my user

Answer (score 1):

A lower-case m represent minutes, while an upper-case m represents months.

You need to change `SimpleDateFormat inSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("ddmmyyyy HH:mm:ss");` to `SimpleDateFormat inSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy HH:mm:ss");`

Comment: ... and use that format for `startDate`: `String startDate="16062019 00:00:00";`

Comment: Used with the string from the question I expect 2020-04-06 00:00:00.000. Which I don't think was the expected. It's not you. It's `SimpleDateFormat` being harder to use correctly than you thought.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).